# How to kill a running script from another script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian, sh

I have a a.sh script that executes a infinite loop with a list of commands in background in a Debian machine and I would like to use another script b.sh to end with a.sh. As far as I know `pkill -f a.sh` is one way of doing it, but I want to know if there is another way of doing it

Comment: [How to stop a script within another script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/421707), [Stopping a running script though another script file](https://askubuntu.com/q/526886), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`man -k kill` shows many commands to kill processes. Watch out `(1)` (general commands) and `(8)` (admin commands). At my system I get (manually filtered):

```
killproc (8)         - Send signals to processes by full path name
docker-container-kill (1) - Kill one or more running containers
docker-kill (1)      - Kill one or more running containers
kill (1)             - terminate a process
killall (1)          - kill processes by name
killall5 (8)         - send a signal to all processes.
pkill (1)            - look up or signal processes based on name and other attributes
skill (1)            - send a signal or report process status
```

Comment: Thanks I will check this commands

Answer (score 0):

If you run a.sh from b.sh you can get the process id of a.sh

**b.sh**

```sh
    a.sh &          # Execute a.sh in the background
    APID=$!         # $APID is now the pid of a.sh

    #do some stuff or wait

    kill -SIGTERM $APID          # Give the process a chance to shut down
    kill -SIGKILL $APID          # Certain kill
```

This way you can kill the particular instance of a.sh if you have multiple concurrent
instances.

Comment: It's not the case but I will have in mind for a future, thanks.

Comment: First, it is better to use name `-kill` instead of number `-9`: Better readable and some numbers differ at different system. Second, give signal `-term` (the default) the first change, so that the process has a chance to clean its work. Signal `-klll` terminates a process immediately.

Comment: Agree kill -SIGTERM $APID; kill -SIGKILL $APID is better.